# Cisco Icons for network diagrams

Tags: diagrams

First of all thanks for this great site. My foray to Latex has been easier than I thought. My company are producing technical documentations of as-built network projects from Structured Cabling to Network Diagram of small office to Datacenter. We have been using MS Office suite of tools, from Word to Visio. My dilemma of producing a cohesive design from page 1 to the last page, where solve by Latex/Tex and we are using Texmaker 3.02 as tools with MiKTex 2.9 as our Latex/TEx platform  and so far it has been very good. Most of our Wire and Cable test results' output were PDF and XML generated by Fluke DTX-1800. With Latex/Tex we are including PDF tests results and network diagrams now with its page numbering as if it belongs to the whole documentation design. Ive seen diagram maker tools like the one for UML and Electrical/Electronics circuits however with my short span of searching from the site I havent seen Cisco network icon type diagram. If there is one, I hope someone can point me to its location. Sorry, English is just my second language if I may not express it easily. Thanks and more power. You have one follower right here.

Comment: Do you need Cisco icons as part of diagrams or as part of your text, that is, each one standing on its own? Do these icons have to be multi-colored or would one color per icon suffice?

Comment: @Christian - I want to do both in some parts of my documents

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The icons are available on the [cisco website](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac50/ac47/2.html). You can download the zip file containing the EPS files, unzip it into a new directory and remove the spaces in the names (which cause problems when you try to include the icons into your LaTeX document) using the shell command `rename 's/ /_/g' *`. You can then include the icons into your document using `\includegraphics` if you also load the package `epstopdf`.

Here's an example of using TikZ chains to build a diagram:

[image: cisco diagram with tikz]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going right,
    diagram item/.style={
        on chain,
        join
    }
]
\node [
    diagram item,
    label=center:Internet
] {\includegraphics{cloud}};

\node [
    diagram item,
    label=right:Cable Modem
] {\includegraphics{cable_modem}};

\node [
    continue chain=going below,
    diagram item,
    label=right:Router
] {\includegraphics{router}};

\node [
    diagram item,
    label=right:Workgroup Switch
] {\includegraphics{workgroup_switch}};

\node [
    start branch=1 going below right,
    diagram item,
    label=below:PC
] {\includegraphics{pc}};

\node [
    start branch=2 going below left,
    diagram item,
    label=below:Supercomputer
] {\includegraphics{supercomputer}};

\node [
    diagram item,
    label=below:Office
] {\includegraphics{end_office}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want to do, sorry for my impatience searching those in the site. I was right in  "asking question" is faster than my search box. thank you very much. Being a newbie I am contented in \includegraphics , Tikz would be my "fun to learn" in the next days. Thank @Jake

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this using PSTricks ?