# Cisco Icons in PSTricks schemabloc

Tags: diagrams, pstricks

I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/cisco-icons-for-network-diagrams), and wonder how to make it using `PSTricks`...

I tried, but failed. The compilation ends, but fails to produce a pdf.
I have the Cisco Icons in a subfolder, and putting them in a `\rput` doesn't work...

This could have a lot of applications, as I'm actually writing my Master Thesis in Network Engineering...

Here's my MWE :

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, float]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-circ, pst-plot, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, pst-sigsys, pstricks-add, pst-eucl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}    

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](0, 1)(10, 5)
        \rput[bl](0,0){\rnode{A}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{Cisco_Icons/pc}}}
        \rput[tr](4,3){\rnode{B}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{Cisco_Icons/pc}}}
        \ncline[nodesep=3pt]{<->}{A}{B}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the console output :

```
Error: /typecheck in --length--
Operand stack:
   1   1
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1951   1   3   %oparray_pop   1950   1   3   %oparray_pop   1934   1   3   %oparray_pop   1820   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1185/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:176/200(L)--   --dict:745/1012(L)--   --dict:173/300(L)--   --dict:43/200(L)--   --dict:38/60(L)--   --dict:181/205(L)--   --dict:41/60(L)--   --dict:43/65(L)--   --dict:7/7(L)--   --dict:7/7(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 531884
GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.59686-1458308792/Archi_centra.pdf ()
```

It seems to ba a Ghostscript problem, but I can't figure it.

**EDIT 1 :** I compile with `TeX+DVI`

**EDIT 2 :** This standalone file is to be included in my `main.tex` like this :

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \input{Schemas/this_standalone}
    \caption{2 PCs linked together}
    \label{fig:pcLinked}
\end{figure}
```

And the `main.tex` HAS to be compiled using `TeX+DVI`, otherwise I'll get other problems with other packagesif compiled with `XeLaTex` (`breakurl` for instance)

**FINAL EDIT :**  All this problem comes from the Cisco Icon package I downloaded. On [their page](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/about/brand-center/network-topology-icons.html), you have 2 choices, for `eps` files : `B/W` or `PSM 3015`. The files of the latter (`PMS 3015`) are misunderstood by Ghostscript, leading to the problem I presented...

What works : `B/W` icons, compiled with `LaTeX`and `TeX+DVI`

Comment: are the `Cisco_Icons/pc` eps images?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded them from the question I saw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with up-to-date TeXLive 2015 I have no problem with your example. However, try to run `xelatex` instead of `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames,table]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}    

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1, -1)(6, 5)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\rnode{A}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{/tmp//pc}}}
    \rput[tr](4,3){\rnode{B}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{/tmp/pc}}}
    \ncline[nodesep=3pt]{<->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is ok with `xelatex`, but I still got the error when including them (with standalonne's `\input`).

Comment: Your example code shows no `\input`

Comment: I got problems when compiling it with `TeX+DVI`, because this file will be included in my `main.tex`, which I must compile with `TeX+DVI`anyway...

Comment: What exactly do you inlcude? If you run your main document with TeX+DVI then you do not need to run standalone. However, you can run your complete document with `xelatex`

Comment: I have now problems with the `breakurl`pakcage (for my bibliography), when runnig with XeLaTex : `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/breakurl/breakurl.sty:311: Undefined control sequence.<argument>\headerps@out  {/burl@stx null def /BU.S { /burl@stx null def } de...
l.311 }
       
?`

Comment: `breakurl` is not needed for `xelatex`. It is done by default.

Comment: I deleted `breakurl`, everything works fine with `xelatex`. Thanks !

Comment: See my edited answer for final solution, which works with everything !

Answer (score 0):

With this code, it compiles with `pdflatex`, provided it is launched with the `--enable-write18` switch, if you're under MiKTeX, `shell-escape` under `TeX Live` or `MacTeX`.

Another solution might be to convert the icons from èps`to`pdf`format, with a tool like`epspdf`.

I slightly simplified your code, as  `pstricks-add` loads a number of the packages you use.

```
\documentclass[￼pstricks, french, float]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add, pst-3dplot, pst-solides3d, , pst-eucl, pst-circ, pst-sigsys}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[labelangle=:U, showgrid=false](0, 1)(10, 5)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\rnode{A}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{Cisco_Icons/pc}}}
    \rput[tr](4,3){\rnode{B}{\includegraphics[width=30pt]{Cisco_Icons/pc}}}
    \ncline[nodesep=3pt]{<->}{A}{B}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, but I compile using TeX+DVI...

Comment: With LaTeX+DVI, the .ps file is  queer: only one icon, and a bounding box appear in GsView, and pstopdf,  yields a .pdf with two icons, but no bounding box. Do you have any reason not to take the pdflatex way?

Comment: Yes, I also use `pst-circ` and other `PSTricks` packages to draw my diagrams...

Comment: Usually it works fine with `pdflatex` and `auto-pst-pdf`, which is done for that.

Comment: I tried with `pdflatex`, and I saw that the template I use requires TeX+DVI => I have no choice. And my work is pretty much advandec to change everything ^^

Comment: Why does it require TeX+DVI? If it is only because of pstricks, it only means the template was not updated (it's been quite a few years that pstricks can be compiled with `pdflatex`). You just have to load `auto-pst-pdf` *after* `pstricks` and add the switch. I can't imagine any other reason for not using `pdflatex. Note you also may convert the .eps files to .pdf format.

Comment: The template hasn't been updated since 2002 :P

Comment: At that time, the way LaTeX+DVI was mandatory. It's not anymore (since 2008 or so). anyway, you can try to compile the template with `pdflatex` and see what happens.

Comment: I don't have the pictures (which also are in .pdf) and the coloured frames. And I compiled my other drawings with pdflatex juste fine, but they don't appear. I have this error : `!pdfTeX error: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex (file ./TFE_pdflatex-pics.pdf): PDF
 inclusion: required page does not exist <1>
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: The MWE I presented don't work...

Comment: I've just compiled it without any problem with pdflatex just adding `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`. With latex+DVI, thers is a problem with `dvips`, but the result is almost correct after I've  used `pstopdf` (almost means I have no bounding box).

Comment: Here is the console output, when compiling with `pdflatex` : http://pastebin.com/B5SyJ0Ve